# How to create service on Windows XP Embedded (Sc.exe is not installed)?

Tags: windows, service, embedded

How to create service on Windows XP Embedded (Sc.exe is not installed) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using VBScript, I found this code from [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/15251-install-windows-service/), OP says it work's perfectly, so maybe worth trying.

```
' Connect to WMI. 
set objServices = GetObjecT("winmgmts:root\cimv2") 

' Obtain the definition of the Win32_Service class. 
Set objService = objServices.Get("Win32_Service") 

' Obtain an InParameters object specific to the Win32_Service.Create method. 
Set objInParam = objService.Methods_("Create").inParameters.SpawnInstance_() 

' Add the input parameters. 
objInParam.Properties_.item("Name") = "GPServer" '< - Service Name 
objInParam.Properties_.item("DisplayName") = "GPServer" '< - Display Name, what you see in the Services control panel 
objInParam.Properties_.item("PathName") = "c:\Server\srvany.exe" '< - Path and Command Line of the executable 
objInParam.Properties_.item("ServiceType") = 16 
objInParam.Properties_.item("ErrorControl") = 0 
objInParam.Properties_.item("StartMode") = "Manual" 
objInParam.Properties_.item("DesktopInteract") = True
'objInParam.Properties_.item("StartName") = ".\Administrator" '< - If null, will run as Local System 
'objInParam.Properties_.item("StartPassword") = "YourPassword" '< - Only populate if the SatrtName param is populated 

'More parameters and return statuses are listed in MSDN: "Create Method of the Win32_Service Class" 


' Execute the method and obtain the return status. 
' The OutParameters object in objOutParams is created by the provider. 
Set objOutParams = objService.ExecMethod_("Create", objInParam) 
wscript.echo objOutParams.ReturnValue
```